# how following C structure is getting expanded to

Tags: c

On this link
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/parport/parport_pc.c?v=2.6.29#L97
they defined a structure superio_struct and initialized as

```
superios[NR_SUPERIOS] = { {0,},};
```

I am not able to understand above initialization has what is it getting initialized to.

What I deduce till now is superios is a structure array of struct superio_struct
and NR_SUPERIOS is defined as 3 hence an array of structure of size 3 
but

```
superios[0]=??
superios[1]=??
superios[2]=??
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just initialising the entire array to zero. The commas are redundant (and not all compilers will allow them). It should really just be:

```
superios[NR_SUPERIOS] = { { 0 } };
```

Comment: I see that has been most confusing to me can you give me some link so that I can understand it better.

Comment: @Bond: all you need to know to understand this is that, in C/C++, if you initialise *part* of an array or struct, i.e. supply fewer initialisation values than there are elements, then the remainder of the elements in the array/struct are initialised to 0. So, in an extreme example, if you just initialise the *first* element to 0, then you are effectively initialising *all* elements to 0. This is what's happening in the example above, except that it's an array of structs, hence the double { }.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for this information.It has been really very confusing.I do not understand why did some one initialized the structure as above.

Comment: @Bond: I *guess* they might have included the trailing commas to make it clear that there are more elements in the struct that are not explicitly being initialised, but I don't really know what was in the mind of the programmer.